# MSCOMM freezing application after some time

Tags: vb6, serial-port

I have an application that always worked perfect.
I have a `MDI`form, that have a menu that open others forms.
Since I placed a new `MSCOMM` component to work with `RFID Reader` this form that uses this `MSCOMM` freezes.

The whole application `DOES NOT` freezes, **just the form that have the `MSCOMM1_OnCom` event**.
I thought it could be some kind of overload, then I tried to use this in the `MSCOMM_OnCom`

```
If MSCOMM1.comEvent = comEvReceive Then

   ///CODE

End If
```

Didn't worked. Then I saw this `RThreshold` that determines how many bytes to receive before a `comEvReceive` event is triggered. I think I didn't understand it well.

Does `RThreshold` determines the `max lenght` that I'll get from the `incomming input` ?

To avoid fire the event `MSCOMM_OnCom` all the time. I thought to set the `RThreshold` to some value bigger than 0, but when I read the `Rfid cards` the lenght of the input read from the `RFID Reader` may vary. So if the `RThreshold` determines especific the max lenght that I'll read from the MSCOMM then I think it will not work for me.

**Update**
I just read this:
`RThreshold is how many characters you receive before MsComm will call 
the OnComm event. 
InputLen is how many characters are in the Input buffer that you will 
get when you call the .Input method. 
In either case you may receive more than the RThreshold number of 
characters when the OnComm event is called by VB`

Is it true? May I set `RThreshold` to 1, but read the whole `mscomm.Input` ?

Comment: How do you define "freezing"?  I find it hard to believe that an serially-connected RFID reader is throwing such volumes of data at you that the event callbacks are consuming all available CPU.  You are probably going to need to post the code that access the MSCOMM control.

Comment: My codeSource are in the notebook, as soon as possible i'll post here.  As I said, it always worked without freezing, before this `RFID MSCOMM`. I have a form that reads the `RFID Cards`, also the user can type manually the `Card ID`. After sometime, it freezes then if you try to type anything, its no longer typing. You need to close that form (not the whole application), then open it again.

Comment: I'd suspect either a program bug that eventually leads to an infinite loop or a device that occasionally "goes insane" and starts streaming garbage data at a high rate.

Comment: VB6 programmers are a bit too comfortable about that kind of mishap.  STA components like MSComm have a knack for flooding the message loop.  Use the SerialPort class to avoid that.

Comment: @HansPassant I guess there is not a `SerialPort` class in vb6, is there? Only `MSComm`

Comment: That's correct, I read it as a vb.net question.  Not sure why.  Lower the baud rate, might help.